# Grid Pathfinding for a real-time game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm working on a pathfinding for a game like Age of Empires I in unity (I need the units to move in 4 directions, not stack between them and surround a target)
My problem is the following: If one unit is surrounded and i assign them as target i want those unit to group close. At the moment if the targeted unit is surrounded all the other that are trying to get to the target go crazy.

```
public void FindPath(Vector3 startPosition, Vector3 targetDestination)
{
    Node StartNode = NodeFromWorldPoint(startPosition);
    Node TargetNode = NodeFromWorldPoint(targetDestination);

    List<Node> OpenList = new List<Node>();
    HashSet<Node> ClosedList = new HashSet<Node>();

    OpenList.Add(StartNode);

    while (OpenList.Count > 0)
    {
        Node CurrentNode = OpenList[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < OpenList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (OpenList[i].FCost < CurrentNode.FCost || OpenList[i].FCost == CurrentNode.FCost && OpenList[i].hCost < CurrentNode.hCost)
            {
                CurrentNode = OpenList[i];
            }
        }
        OpenList.Remove(CurrentNode);
        ClosedList.Add(CurrentNode);

        if (CurrentNode == TargetNode)
        {
            GetFinalPath(StartNode, TargetNode);
        }

        foreach (Node NeighborNode in CurrentNode.neighbors)
        {
            if (NeighborNode.blocked || ClosedList.Contains(NeighborNode) || NeighborNode.occupied)
            {
                continue;
            }
            int MoveCost = CurrentNode.gCost + ManhattenDistance(CurrentNode, NeighborNode);

            if (MoveCost < NeighborNode.gCost || !OpenList.Contains(NeighborNode))
            {
                NeighborNode.gCost = MoveCost;
                NeighborNode.hCost = ManhattenDistance(NeighborNode, TargetNode);
                NeighborNode.parentNode = CurrentNode;

                if (!OpenList.Contains(NeighborNode))
                {
                    OpenList.Add(NeighborNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void GetFinalPath(Node startingNode, Node endNode)
{
    List<Node> FinalPath = new List<Node>();
    Node CurrentNode = endNode;

    while (CurrentNode != startingNode)
    {
        FinalPath.Add(CurrentNode);
        CurrentNode = CurrentNode.parentNode;
    }

    FinalPath.Reverse();

    finalPath = FinalPath;
}

int ManhattenDistance(Node nodeA, Node nodeB)
{
    int dist = (int)Vector3.Distance(nodeA.transform.position, nodeB.transform.position);

    return dist;
}

public Node NodeFromWorldPoint(Vector3 worldPosition)
{
    var nod = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(worldPosition, 10);
    var nodos = new List<Node>();
    foreach (var item in nod)
    {
        if (item.GetComponent<Node>())
            nodos.Add(item.GetComponent<Node>());
    }

    float dist = Mathf.Infinity;
    Node closest = null;
    foreach (var item in nodos)
    {
        var ds = Vector3.Distance(worldPosition, item.transform.position);
        if (ds < dist)
        {
            dist = ds;
            closest = item;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I have not played Age of Empires I so I'm not 100% sure I know what kind of movement you're trying to recreate (posting a video would be helpful), but if I understand you correctly you're looking for chessboard like movement (no diagonals).
[EDIT] OP provided a visual link for reference and it is chessboard like movement.

It looks like you're trying to implement A*. Taking a look at the sample you posted, I found a few points which may be causing you problems.

1. Initializing Nodes

Are you initializing/resetting the nodes after running a search? I don't see where you're doing that in the sample, so unless you're doing it in another piece of code, you could be using old cost values when running the search multiple times.

2. Admissible heuristic (Manhattan Distance)

Assuming you're trying to implement A*, a key part of the algorithm is that your heuristic is admissible, which mean it does not underestimate cost. You called your heuristic function Manhattan Distance, but your implementation is actually Euclidean distance (see the difference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)). If your units can only move in four directions (i.e. up, down, left, right) and not eight, this could be why your search is not working properly.

As a side note, if you could post a video of the behavior or be more descriptive than, "go crazy" that would help.
[EDIT] OP provided a video to demonstrate behavior.

[UPDATE]

If the behavior you're trying to get is to get as close as possible, I would consider implementing some sort of logic to determine when a unit is "surrounded" and then through some algorithm (a greedy approach is probably ok) selecting a closest node as the target.

So if the state looks something like this:

```
X X X
X O X
X X X
```

Where the X's are the red units and the O is the blue unit, the next "target" node a new red unit would target to surround the blue unit would look something like:

```
T T T T T
T X X X T
T X O X T
T X X X T
T T T T T
```

Where T's are the possible target nodes

Comment: Could you post the solution? It would be helpful to other people who have similar issues/questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying.
I wasn't resetting nodes correctly so i fixed that. But the problem Persist.
This is the kind of movement i'm looking for: (47min aprox)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPM0Kn_IS-U

I want them to not share the same grid space but i want them to encricle the target, and if there is no room near it, they stay as close as possible.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7iUghtIoCQ&feature=youtu.be

You can see that they can't go to the other sector if someone is already inside. If they want to enter the same sector they wait for a short period and recalculates the path. The problem starts when all the spaces are occupied and they can't find the way to the target, they start going back and dancing until they find a space. I want that if there is no way to reach its target, they at least stay as close as possible.

Thanks again! English isn't my main languague, sorry if i'm not clear enough